# Convert an unsigned 16 bit int to a signed 16 bit int in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, unsigned, signed

I'm writing a datalog parser for a robot controller, and what's coming in from the data log is a number in the range of 0 - 65535 (which is a 16 bit unsigned integer if I'm not mistaken). I'm trying to convert that to a signed 16 bit integer to display to the user (since that was the actual datatype before the logger changed it).

Can someone give me a hand?

Example:

What the values should be
(0, -1, -2, -3, -4)

What the values are
(0, 65535, 65534, 65533, 65532)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried explicit casting?

```
UInt16 x = 65535;
var y = (Int16)x; // y = -1
```

Comment: Is going to crash if `[X] Check for Arithmetic Overflow` is on.

Answer (score 2):

Using `unchecked` here avoids a crash if `[X] Check for Arithmetic Overflow` is on:

```
UInt16 x = 65535;
Int16 y = unchecked((Int16)x);
```

Answer (score -2):

Or like this

[image: Or like this]

Just check if `UI16>32767` if yes, `I16=UI16-65536`, otherwise = `UI16`